# Blank page when using "Xamarin Forms" with "MvvmCross"

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a problem with Xamarin Forms and Mvvm Cross on Android. In my app, I need to navigate between  Master Detail page and my other pages that are not a part of my master detail page.   At some point (after I minimize and resume an app)  when I navigate somewhere I get blank page with no UI instead of an expected page. No exceptions are thrown. Below you can find a link to a simple project that you can reproduce the issue:

https://github.com/grinh/blankpage

Here are steps to reproduce it:

1. Launch the app
2. Tap on "QUICK GUIDE" button
3. Close app with back button
4. Open app by tapping on its icon
5. Tap on "QUICK GUIDE"
   At this point, you should see blank screen instead of a correct page. I would appreciate any help with this issue.

Below you can find simplified classes that can be used to reproduce issue. (I use MvvmCross ver. 5.6.3 and Xamarin Forms ver. 2.5.0.121934):

LoginPage.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:MvxContentPage x:TypeArguments="vm:LoginViewModel" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BlankScreenApp.ViewModels;assembly=BlankScreenApp"
             x:Class="BlankScreenApp.Views.LoginPage">
    <views:MvxContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Quick guide" x:Name="QuickGuideButton" Clicked="QuickGuideButtonClicked"   />
        </StackLayout>
    </views:MvxContentPage.Content>
</views:MvxContentPage>
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
  [MvxContentPagePresentation(NoHistory = true)]
    public partial class LoginPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void QuickGuideButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            await Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>().Navigate<QuickGuideViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

QuickGuide.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:MvxContentPage x:TypeArguments="viewModels:QuickGuideViewModel" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:BlankScreenApp.ViewModels;assembly=BlankScreenApp"
             x:Class="BlankScreenApp.Views.QuickGuidePage">
    <views:MvxContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="40">
            <Label Text="Some text comes here." />
        </StackLayout>
    </views:MvxContentPage.Content>
</views:MvxContentPage>
```

QuickGuide.xaml.cs

```
[MvxContentPagePresentation(NoHistory = true)]
    public partial class QuickGuidePage
    {
        public QuickGuidePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

CoreApp.cs

```
   public class CoreApp : MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            RegisterNavigationServiceAppStart<LoginViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Setup.cs

```
public class Setup : MvxFormsAndroidSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
    {

    }

    protected override MvxFormsApplication CreateFormsApplication()
    {
        return new BlankScreenApp.App();
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new BlankScreenApp.CoreApp();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new DebugTrace();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "BlankScreenApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
    public class MainActivity : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Questions with external links are not great for SO. Few are going to visit that link, that link will be dead in no time, and no one is going to install an app. Can you provide a [mcve] that shows the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Providing a “Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example” is hard since I’m not quite sure what is the cause of my problem, but I will try.

Comment: Software development is an iterative process, and debugging is a key part of that process. You are asking us to debug this for you, but the fact is that SO is a _terrible_ debugger. Debugging will help you isolate the problem, which leads naturally to a [mcve]. See also: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thank you for you response. It was not my intention to insult you in any way. I have edited my question and added all necesary classes that are needed reproduce problem just after I sent you my reply.  I would appreciate any help with this issue.